# Ubuntu ARM requirements (CLI only)

Tags: ubuntu, arm, requirements

I am using Ubuntu ARM as testing platform on a QEMU emulator. The emulator has 256MB of RAM, but I'm wondering: what are the minimum requirements for running Ubuntu ARM? (CLI only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean "what's the minimum RAM it will run in", you can set the RAM that qemu provides to the emlated system with the `-m` option. Keep halving it until the system won't boot or becomes unusably slow, then double it one step back.

Of course, it also depends what command-line applications you want to run: gcc will take hundreds of megabytes if it wants.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to just try it, if they have jeos for arm start with that, if there is an existing already built boot image, start with that and apt-get remove (and purge) stuff you dont need to get a smaller image, then start trimming the memory requirements down.